# Is there a verb for making (appreciative/agreement/attentive) sounds during conversation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb for giving feedback to someone with non-word sounds during conversation, including not specifically using filler words, in order to indicate attentiveness, agreement or appreciation, etc.?

I have searched for this word in all kinds of places and understood it to be a form of vocal (non-verbal) communication and as a subset of paralanguage. However, none of it helped finding a verb.

Answer (score 4):

In the field of [Critical Discourse Analysis](http://www.strath.ac.uk/aer/materials/6furtherqualitativeresearchdesignandanalysis/unit3/whatiscriticaldiscourseanalysis/) (CDA), these language features, present only in spoken discourse, are called "acknowledgement tokens" or "backchannels". From the textbook *Language and Power*:

> Interviewers do not affiliate or disaffiliate with interviewees. They avoid '**acknowledgement tokens**' such as 'mmmh', 'uh uh' or 'really', which in ordinary conversation fill pauses and offer '**backchannels**'.

In the context of this citation, acknowledgement tokens move conversations along by implying subtle support for the speaker. They lubricate the conversation and avoid awkward pauses, and they mainly comprise the non-word sounds of support you hear.  Backchannels are similar and overlap to a degree, and they operate under the pretext that speech functions like an alternating current between speaker and listener. In this function, the listener has the subtle ability to influence the speaker's focus or "channel" by doing things such as audibly announcing consent:

> - mm-hhmm
> - uh-huh

completing the speaker's sentence:

> A: It was just, was just--
>
> B: --Too diificult, I know.

asking for clarification:

> - Wai--what?

or adding emphasis:

> - "Seriously!"
> - "Wow!"

There is no accordant verb for the concept of acknowledgement tokens, but if you said "backchanneled" you would likely be understood by people in the CDA field.

Comment: I came across [this interesting paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378216614001222) on the subject, making the point (among others) that "backchannels" are used for much more than *passively indicating that the primary communication channel is still "open", and that the addressee is following everything being sent through it*. Specifically, they can carry ***proactive** "tokens"* as well as *reactive* ones, and the backchannel is used for other things besides helping to regulate conversational turn-taking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This relationship of power is a complicated one. Like when you make an elaborate request for a raise from your boss, and her response is "mm-hhmm". Is that a validation or a sign of disapproval? And there are some complicated [ideas](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=13713) about what it means when men and women use either "uh" or "um".

Answer (score 1):

[*Murmur*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/murmur_2) may be the best catchall for expressing these kinds of "vocal (non-verbal) communication," though it's typically accompanied by a prepositional (*of*) phrase indicating the type of emotion the murmur is conveying. Just a few examples:

> - a murmur of agreement
> - a murmur of approval
> - a murmur of encouragement

and so on.

When people do this, they make a sound that either falls short of being a verbalization, or the verbalization is so indistinct or quiet that it takes a back seat to the "emotional content" of the sound produced.

Edit: As the OP was requesting a verb, note that murmur works equally well as a verb. For example, you could say:

> The listener
>
> - murmured in agreement.
> - murmured in approval.
> - murmured in encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

[Many times](http://fiction) it's just **coded as such** :-)

> Fantasy & Science Fiction - Volume 72, Issues 428-430 - Page 84 1986 -
> ‎Snippet view
>
> "The juice," she intoned, and everyone but Fran **made appreciative
> sounds**. "Now," Jenny said, "pay attention, Fran. At my signal,
> everyone places their fingers in the juice — thumbs, too."
> For one full minute we must have complete silence.

"**Er**(r) ..." one of them, showing hesitation, but one could use it for reserved approval:

> The Windsor Magazine: An Illustrated Monthly for Men and Women 1937
>
> She nodded. **" Er . . ."** she began, " the window. . . ." " Yes,
> that's a fine idea, makes the window look pretty all those cornflowers
> growin' there. Well, good morning, ma'am." " Good morning," said Mrs.
> Robertson. The door was shut. The whistling ...

Also, one can use the name of the sound:

> Multicultural Manners: Essential Rules of Etiquette for ... -- ‎More editions
> _
>
> In most parts of Asia making sounds while
> eating is acceptable and encouraged. In Hong Kong and in other
> countries, **lip-smacking** tells the cook his food is delicious.
> **Belching** is another complimentary sign, as in some parts of the
> Philippines

say, e.g.:

> [Once Were Cannibals](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cLoGBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22slurp%20%20slurp%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xnokVemTGLjasATBkYHQBw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22slurp%20%20slurp%22&f=false)rev 2/2015 - Page 21 John N. Tunui - 2013
>
> “**(Slurp, slurp)**, okay ... you can **(slurp)** with your **(slurp,
> slurp)** damn uncle **(slurp)**.”
>
> “Yea, we can play with our uncle, yea, yea ....” They danced around
> their uncle, muddying him with their playful hug.
>
> “(**Slurp, slurp, slurp),** help ....”
>
> “Uncle Ki'i ..

In Japanese they seem to have names for many such sounds:

> Nihongo: a Japanese approach to Japanese - Page 442
>
> Makoto Sugawara, ‎Burritt Sabin - 1985 - In Japan it is considered
> poor manners to make sounds while eating, especially during formal
> meals. But during informal meals with close friends the Japanese make
> ***kori-kori, saku-saku. gori-gori***. . . sounds with relish.

kori-kori S: The sound made when scratching or chewing something hard.
saku-saku: a crips, crunching sound

Answer (score 0):

These are sometimes called *[minimal encouragers](http://www.talking-therapy.org.uk/counselling/minimal-encouragers/)*:

> small signals that let the speaker know you are listening and
>   understanding – words like “uh-huh”, “yes”, “no”, “mmm”, and little
>   actions like nodding that show you are engaged in listening.

I like the ring of that!

Answer (score -1):

A Google Books search finds almost a hundred matches for the phrase "grunted his assent," including such instances as this one from Percy Marshall, [*Masters of English Poetry*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oeQ-AAAAIAAJ&q=%22grunted+his+assent%22&dq=%22grunted+his+assent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EHUkVYClDtLzoATq24GQAw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBjhQ) (1966) [combined snippets]:

> On the lowest level it is possible to convey limited meaning by using noise before it has become word. We sometimes read, in a piece of fiction for instance, how "he **grunted his assent**" — which is one stage beyond "he nodded his assent". The grunt when organized becomes the simple affirmative—Ja, Yea, Yes ...

And from John Oxenford, "[His Umbrella](https://books.google.com/books?id=9MI-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22grunted+his+assent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kHYkVaqjLNGrogSIt4D4BQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAThQ#v=onepage&q=%22grunted%20his%20assent%22&f=false)," in, *Somebody's Luggage: The Christmas Numbers of "All the Year Round"* (1862):

> "Ho-ho-ho!" roared the landlord. "Why, of course it would, if it went out on a wet evening like this. Well, that's a good 'un. The gentleman has given it her there, and no mistake ; hasn't he Jim?"
>
> The man in the shaggy great-coat **grunted his assent**, with a low chuckle.

And from Charles Holder, [*The Ivory King: A Popular History of the Elephant and Its Allies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lb8pAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22grunted+his+assent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tHokVe25K8iSoQT15IGwCw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgy#v=onepage&q=%22grunted%20his%20assent%22&f=false) in (1886):

> The next day the parties appeared in court, and the trainer subpoened his elephant in his defence. As the animal could not squeeze up the stairs to the police court, the latter was held in the corridor below. When asked if he had been injured, Pickaninny [the elephant's name, I regret to say] moved his head negatively ; and when the inquiry was made if he was treated well, he bobbed his head up and down, and **grunted his assent** in a very decided manner.

Answer (score -2):

In America, quiet agreement is usually written something like  "mmhmmm", which is a closed-mouth version of "uh-huh".

So if there is not a perfect verb for this,  I would nominate  *to mm-hmmm**  (they  mm-hmmmed appreciatively, he mm-hmmmed).

Or if that seems silly, try "hummed in appreciation". That's close, and it's an accepted verb (I can imagine bees humming , rather than buzzing, when they are busily working together, presumably in agreement).

While we're on animal metaphors, you could try **purr**. This is a sound associated with contentment and appreciation.